# Power over Ethernet device not powering up but computers can use same outlet for data

Tags: power-over-ethernet

We have an office where a Power over Ethernet device cannot power up; however, if a computer is plugged into the same outlet, it has no trouble using it for data transfer (100 Mbps).

In fact, we have multiple outlets with the same exact problem, which leads me to think that the person doing the installation made a mistake with the wiring rather than the drop from the data room to the outlet simply being damaged.

I used a voltmeter to test the ends of the cable but was unable to find anything close to 50v DC (PoE apparently uses 44 - 57v DC).

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here and how I could adjust the wiring of the drop to allow PoE to work?

Comment: I'm going to guess that power is not fed to all outlets, check at the switch or router.  Power supply was probably only provided for outlets were a POE device was expected to be attached.  In anycase, the power suppied comes from a source at the other end of the wire, power is not a standard pair in ethernet, it's added to an unused pair.

Comment: [Here](http://find-a-poe.com/product/WS-POE-8-48v60w/?gclid=CP-5_ryas8ICFYKPMgodZhwAiQ) is an example of an 8-port POE Power supply. There are also other configurations (like single) available.  The cable out of the router/switch would be a short jumper to the POE power supply IN, then another short jumper back out to the patch panel that connects to the wall jack in the office.

Comment: @Tyson I've tried plugging the device into the PoE switch in the data room and it powers up fine, so the problem is definitely with the drops themselves (which are patched directly into this switch).

Comment: you need an ethernet continuity tester then like [this](http://shack.net/15WqtFS) not suggesting that particular one, there are many available, I googled quick for inexpensive. You can even buy them at Lowes or Home Depot these days.  That's about the only way to troubleshoot it, using a meter is about impossible and really only tests for opens not mis-wired jacks.

Comment: Is everything patch panels and jumper cables or did they crimp male ends on in the data room? If they crimped male ends onto the building cables that's most likely where the problem is. Patch panels and wall jacks are relatively easy to spot check for wiring issues.

Comment: I've just ordered this http://www.ncix.com/detail/trendnet-tc-nt2-network-cable-tester-05-35316.htm. Looking forward to understanding what's happening here!

Comment: Yep.  the nice thing about those testers is you can use it to test both the building cabling and jacks and also the patch cables themselves.  We once provided labor for a project where the "corporate IT dept" sent all the supplies and materials to be used.  That way they would have "high quality materials from approved suppliers".  About 1 in 6 of the 3' patch cables and 1 in 10 of the 6' cables they sent to be used were bad and unusable.

Comment: Sounds like the IT department was trying to save money on supplies by getting you to try to reuse some junk they had lying around. Cutting corners on network cables is the best example of a false economy. Imagine the cost and time involved in troubleshooting those cables once they'd been installed!